# Verificar automaticamente variáveis quantitativas em R

Tags: r, data.frame, sapply

Tenho um banco de dados aqui e preciso verificar automaticamente quais sao variaveis quantitativas. Meu orientador diz que preciso usar `sapply` e a função `is.numeric` e criar um codigo que retorne um vetor de verdadeiros e falsos indicando quais variaveis sao numericas.

Poderiam me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Isso, você vai usar o `sapply` com a função `is.numeric`. Em resumo, o `sapply` vai aplicar a cada variável (coluna) do seu data.frame a função  `is.numeric` para saber se aquela é uma variável (coluna) numérica.

Gerando uma base para demonstração:

```
df <- data.frame(numeric1 = 1:10,
                 factor = factor(c("a", "b")),
                 character = "texto",
                 numeric2 = 10:1,
                 logical = TRUE ,
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
str(df)
 $ numeric1 : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 $ factor   : Factor w/ 2 levels "a","b": 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 2
 $ character: chr  "texto" "texto" "texto" "texto" ...
 $ numeric2 : int  10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
 $ logical  : logi  TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE TRUE ...
```

Usando o `sapply` com `is.numeric` para gerar um vetor indicando quais colunas são numéricas:

```
numericas <- sapply(df, is.numeric)
numericas
numeric1    factor character  numeric2   logical 
     TRUE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE     FALSE
```

Agora você pode usar esse vetor para filtrar o data.frame:

```
df[,numericas]
  numeric1 numeric2
1         1       10
2         2        9
3         3        8
4         4        7
5         5        6
6         6        5
7         7        4
8         8        3
9         9        2
10       10        1
```